# Typescript: Enum extensions (namespace) causes error ...(intermediate value) is not iterable

Tags: typescript, enums

Update: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAssECNgCcAKKIEsDO3MHsQoBvAWACgooAXYAYwAsoBeKAclsbYBooB6PlADKYAA7J4wKAEM6dYLgpVpAEyxFWbVep79BACWnYoEfNmoy5C7EpP4VKadXzIW7Uw+ROXPWwCtkGHs3NgCglV9KKARpBABPcJCY+PC2CgBfAG4KChBpCAVRWSk4RBR0ZCxcAiIyKOAAD1EXCwAzMBA6ahqafCFqZEwQAHMAClEMAC5YeCQ0DBw8QgBKafNBkZJbKglqMGQiUrmKqqWQAG0JyoBdbKj0jJzyajiJqAA5QlRBgDdMABtgMNgCoTosasZWABRBp0f5gBwAHiO5QW1UIvAARNohpioAAfKCYzgMTEAPieAgAKgB5AAiNIAtDAhi5eAB3KTYBj4MD-FTRYAIGQIQG9KBgbBST4gb6YP6A4GgtFnYwMFDAAB0H3wFmw+yk7IYcSgnKgdGkIA4moogIsKPmlXBhBg0lEQmAe1E02IUHOAGtgCahjMyo7TjVrgB+aYOsHoi7XKDpNx1KgeRzOZDTc5xlU1TVhezXbj+QL2HN5p0JzXJBLFjJ3W2e0PHfMut3TF4TfCtVuo6tnV3uz1iVONp7tTrdQhQbCiTCeeOq0YQb1QQNxXs0V7AbdViMdkde1b98POxNbKKYPujA8X4cer3nNdJgCErA6DlaQxByyvVBUPeCbDi+ohJqwwFDm6YFJlGUZ+rc2xnsuNSga+b6aqIkoMKMmr4VBaFuk+YiwW+yx3IBKHtiAj6jqIZGaq0LhQrIuGjIwAIqLwPz-swZIAVR1GDkRDEYVhOF4fh86LgOh4gNgHEMFxMjGDKcoKkCIKoYQ2DLMsyHpAZ9y2IRR6wW4ACCyBeHETHIPgECjCAwDssInp3rMckPjBr76ZRUC7PshxeeeIG+eBUDwYhdwPOQFDMa4ox2lAohQCGZkgP+aZzguS40YpaVGDqsq-ACWnKiJukUY88XkHQun4ICmr-PgYyZcONXkEAA)

I figured out that it's specifically the export of the function inside the namespace. If I remove `export`, the code works.

---

I'm trying to setup some permissions control on my app, various assets use this.

I also wanted an easy way to spider permissions, so that moderator was automatically granted the permissions of jrMod, and jrMod had the authority of babyMod.

Using Member.hasPermission(MemberPermission.jrMod) would grant authority to jrMod, and moderator, as well as admin because `hasPermission` also checks to see if the member has `tech` and `admin` permission.

***This code works***, if I remove the namespace bit below, otherwise I get an error at the marked line

```
(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not iterable
```

Or, if I use `push` to do a similar thing, I get

```
Found non-callable @@iterator
```

Here's the code

```
enum MemberPermission {
  tech = 'tech', // Supreme access
  admin = 'admin', // Has most access
  moderator = 'moderator',
  jrMod = 'jrMod',
  babyMod = 'babyMod'
};

namespace MemberPermission {
  export function fromString(perm: string): MemberPermission {
    return (MemberPermission as any)[perm];
  }
}

type NonPrivilegedPermissions = Exclude<MemberPermission, "admin" | "tech">
let MemberPermissionMapSetup: {
  [key in NonPrivilegedPermissions]?: NonPrivilegedPermissions[]
} = {
  moderator: [MemberPermission.jrMod],
  jrMod: [MemberPermission.babyMod]
};

let MemberPermissionMap: typeof MemberPermissionMapSetup = {};

function spiderPermissions(mp: keyof typeof MemberPermissionMapSetup): NonPrivilegedPermissions[] {
  if (MemberPermissionMapSetup[mp] != undefined) {

    // V V V V THIS LINE
    MemberPermissionMap[mp] = [...MemberPermissionMap[mp] ?? [], ...MemberPermissionMapSetup[mp]!];
    MemberPermissionMapSetup[mp]!.forEach((child, v) => {
      MemberPermissionMap[mp]!.push(...spiderPermissions(child as NonPrivilegedPermissions))
    })
  }
  MemberPermissionMap[mp] = Array.from(new Set(MemberPermissionMap[mp]));
  return MemberPermissionMap[mp] ?? [];
}

for (let p in MemberPermission) {
  spiderPermissions(p as NonPrivilegedPermissions);
}

console.log(MemberPermissionMap);
```

Comment: can you share a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) where the error can be seen?

Comment: @TobiasS. added. I figured out that's the export insice the namespace, if i remove that one keyword, it's fixed, but then the code doesn't work because other parts depend on that function

Answer (score 0):

Update: A resolution

So the entire trouble seems to be that one of my namespace "extension methods" on MemberPermission was named `toString`. Merely renaming this function fixed the issue.

Short of a try-catch, there's no way to prevent the error.

Looping over the members of MemberPermission,

- all (including methods) passsed `hasOwnProperty`,
- all had `typeof string`
- all had `String` for `.constructor.name`,
- `.call` returned undefined for all members

So that methods aren't being spidered, I renamed them to be prefixed with `__`, so that I can check the name in the loop.

If I did something like this again, I wouldn't use this structure so that these MemberPermission methods weren't part of MemberPermission, but it's fine here. Changing it would require more time than it's worth as all this code is only invoked at server start.

---

Old answer:

A working solution for now was to move the `namespace` declaration to after the call to `spiderPermissions()`, which feels kind of weird, an may not always work in different situations. What if spiderPermission needs to call one of those methods? I don't know.

Another solution removing the enum's methods (namespace functions) to just normal functions.

If anyone has one, I'd still like a solution that actually addresses the problem.